# How can I use view.layer properties?

Tags: swift

I can't use view.layer.borderColor and borderWidth.
Just see error message.

`'layer' is only available in iOS 13.0 or newer.`

[1](https://blogfiles.pstatic.net/MjAxOTA5MjRfMjkx/MDAxNTY5MjU1OTk0Njgy.lEBzPfjuatrPQLQWmO6J2X0u7uEwYPv88cCvzGRff2kg.kD5sen-dRqiZhL8krTdeBLW6wInPDfvMLXOnFbepfaMg.PNG.whdals0/%EC%8A%A4%ED%81%AC%EB%A6%B0%EC%83%B7_2019-09-24_%EC%98%A4%EC%A0%84_1.24.41.png)

I use Xcode Version 11.0 (11A420a), and Swift 4

It's my code.

```
func allBorder(view: AnyObject, cgColor : CGColor, borderWidth : CGFloat){
        view.layer.borderColor = cgColor
        view.layer.borderWidth = borderWidth
    }
```

It worked well, but after a long time trying to modify it, it suddenly stops working.

What steps should I take to use view.layer on 13.0 and below?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use `layer` on `AnyObject`. Use it on `UIView` instead:

```
func allBorder(view: UIView, cgColor : CGColor, borderWidth : CGFloat){
```

Comment: Thank you. Sulthan.   :)

Answer (score 4):

You need to change view type from AnyObject to UIView.

```
func allBorder(view: UIView, cgColor : CGColor, borderWidth : CGFloat){
        view.layer.borderColor = cgColor
        view.layer.borderWidth = borderWidth
    }
```

So that iOS can figure out view has layer property on it.